# Redirection url provoc a lost of information in my url

Tags: url, redirect

I'm trying to do a redirection from my host : http://www.carthera.com to http://www.carthera.eu,

Everything looks fine, but when i try to go on another page with carthera.eu I have this :

```
http://carthera.eu/index.php?page=carthera&ssmenu=0
```

But with carthera.com I just have the

```
http://carthera.com
```

Does anyone know where it comes from and how can i fix this ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, the problem was that the host used an Iframe to display carthera.com. So basically when I went on carthera.com, I would have an iframe with carthera.eu. So the information for the get are not displayed in carthera.com but in the iframe carthera.eu ...